# Installing express.js on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, express

I installed express.js under `C:\node`. The express directory is there. When I go to create a new app using the command `express mkapp` it says "express is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Do I need to add it to the global path? How? Any thoughts would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install express using `npm install -g express`, not by adding the file.

Answer (score 0):

**npm install -g express**   may not work for you start your DOS in Admin mode 
go to start -> write cmd -> right click cmd application ->  click on run as admin -> then use the **npm install -g express** to install it with full admin permission